# Editing Jenkins sysconfig not changing home directory - RHEL

Tags: jenkins, rhel

I've edited /etc/sysconfig/jenkins and changed the following from /var/lib/jenkins to /app/jenkins in order to move to a volume with more storage allocated.

The problem is even after restart jenkins home directory still shows /var/lib/jenkins. What do I need to change in order for this change to take effect?

```
## Path:        Development/Jenkins
## Description: Jenkins Automation Server
## Type:        string
## Default:     "/app/jenkins"
## ServiceRestart: jenkins
#
# Directory where Jenkins store its configuration and working
# files (checkouts, build reports, artifacts, ...).
#
JENKINS_HOME="/app/jenkins"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to ultimately get this to work by using

```
export JENKINS_HOME /app/jenkins
```

Comment: `export JENKINS_HOME="/app/jenkins"`